# regex to verify GMT&Chinese date time format

Tags: javascript, regex, time, format

I want to validate the date- time format which is like 'Wed Oct 25 2017 12:59:00 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)' for this i am looking for a regex.

Tried few combinations but those did not work for me.

Comment: Please try this regex: /[a-zA-z]{3,3}\s[a-zA-z]{3,3}\s[\d]{2,2}\s[\d]{4,4}\s[\d]{2,2}:[\d]{2,2}:[\d]{2,2}\sGMT\+[\d]{4}/

Comment: Do you need to validate the Chinese characters in parentheses as well?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) instead to [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and validate your datetime string:

```js
var time = 'Wed Oct 25 2017 12:59:00 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)';
console.log(moment(time, 'ddd, MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ').isValid());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

The format string `'ddd, MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ'` tells Moment how to read your GMT+0800 (China Standard Time) input string.

<sub>Note: All date objects created with Moment, no matter, the time zone will default to the current time zone, unless specified directly, e.g. `.zone("+08:00")` To get UTC times back, use `moment.utc()` instead. For more information on time zones, check out the section [Moment Time Zones](http://stackabuse.com/moment-js-a-better-date-library-for-javascript/#momenttimezones).</sub>

Further reading: [Moment.js: A Better Date Library for JavaScript](http://stackabuse.com/moment-js-a-better-date-library-for-javascript/)

Comment: +1: parsing date and time is a hard problem that only gets harder when you try to do it with multiple languages and a regex. moment.js is a library that is essentially purpose built to do what you want to achieve.